# Automatic logout by calling the logout endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

In terms of OneDrive logout documentation below:

[image]

Now it works for me by making the browser load this URL. Basically it will show the Microsoft Logout Page and then the user needs to select the logged-in account and logout. like below

[image]

However, for logout, is it possible to let backend or frontend call some endpoint instead of using the browser to load some URL, so that I can make the whole log-out process automated.

I tried to send a GET request in the frontend by using the endpoint in the doc. However, after that, when redirecting the browser to the login URL again, it still used the previous account and skipped the login step.

I used the Code Flow.

Thanks so much.

Comment: I'm *pretty* sure the answer is no. You'll need to actually redirect the user to sign them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the answer clearer, as Junnas has suggested, it is impossible.

When we send a sign-out request using the OpenId connect protocol we must redirect the user to the `end_session_endpoint` for sign-out.

The endpoint is `GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout`.

"post_logout_redirect_uri" is the URL that the user should be redirected to after successful sign out. This URL must match one of the redirect URIs registered for your application in the app registration portal. If post_logout_redirect_uri is not included, the user is shown a generic message.

See details here: [Send a sign-out request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code#send-a-sign-out-request).